# Failure in trying to insert contents in table sql server and java

Tags: java, sql-server

So I am trying to do a insert statement. The values that `paramDataArray` hold is `paramDataArray[]="kkkkkkk"`. Everything works until I go to `executeupdate` at the bottom then it throws an exception. Which is Invalid object name '`innovationtable`'.

To create my table I do this

```
 try{ 

        mydataobject.executeQuery("create table innovationtable(ReqName text, " +
                                  "Locbook text," +
                                  "Datewanted text, " +
                                  "Duration text, " +
                                  "Client text, " +
                                  "Speaker text, " +
                                  "Demo textt); ");
      }
      catch (SQLException ex)
      {

      }
```

Below is what I do to insert into the table;

```
      String insertQuery = "insert into innovationtable(ReqName, Locbook, Datewanted, Duration, Client,Speaker,Demo)" + 
              " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

             // setting up prepared statement for executing the insert Query
              PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mydataobject.getConnection().prepareStatement(insertQuery);

              preparedStatement.setString(1, paramDataArray[0]);
              preparedStatement.setString(2, paramDataArray[1]);
              preparedStatement.setString(3, paramDataArray[2]);
              preparedStatement.setString(4, paramDataArray[3]);
              preparedStatement.setString(5, paramDataArray[4]);
              preparedStatement.setString(6, paramDataArray[5]);
              preparedStatement.setString(7, paramDataArray[6]);

              preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

exception thrown:

> Invalid object name 'innovationtable'. at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown
>   Source) at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   a00679381.assignment1.servlet.mainservlet.doGet(mainservlet.java:123)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I'd be checking for any exceptions when you create the table

Comment: If your code really looks like that (empty catch block when creating the table) then your `create table` obviously failed and you ignored the error.

Comment: @Jim Garrison thank you for that definitely didn't see that

Comment: @JimGarrison I found the issue and now it goes through but actually works the I still get an error though that says statement does not return a resultset? Can I ignore this or is it something i need to fix eventhough it works

Comment: No, you cannot use `executeQuery` with a DDL statement. Use `Statement#execute()` instead.

Comment: Unrelated: the `text` datatype has been deprecated since 2005 and should not be used any longer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187993%28v=sql.90%29.aspx